# How to get the global module installation folder in Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to access the location on the disk of the global node modules (from within a node module).

I know I can enter `npm root -g` on the command line, but this is awfully SLOW.

Does any of you know a way to get this information reliably and in a timely fashion (without requiring users to setup any global Env variables)?

Answer (score 13):

You probably cannot do this in pure javascript way, but you can just look for the npm location:

```
$ which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/npm
... /usr/local/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

so the global `node_modules` is `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, It can be done by executing the command : where npm

Comment: if you run "where" on powershell it will run Where-Object command. If you are on powershell you should run it with exe extension like this:

where npm  # prints nothing
where.exe npm
D:\Programs\nodejs\npm
D:\Programs\nodejs\npm.cmd